# PHP: Display outputting variable

Tags: php

Whenever I see output it displays $iV is less than 10. but i want `$iV` to display the number instead of the name of variable what am i doing wrong here?

```
$iV = 7; 


if($iV > 10)
{ 

  $r = '$iV is greater than 10'; 
}

else
{

  $r = '$iV is less than 10';
}

echo "<p>$r</p>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`). Variables are not escaped in single quoted strings.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> **Note:** Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Working code:

```
$iV = 7; 

if($iV > 10)
{ 
  $r = "$iV is greater than 10"; 
}
else
 {
  $r = "$iV is less than 10";
}

echo "<p>$r</p>"
```